# Did I implement this peculiar integral in the right way?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, matlab

I have such a integral at hand, I need to integrate it numerically in matlab.
or if somebody can give a simple answer implemented in any language, it's also appreciated.

$$\int_0^a \int_0^a  \phi(x_1) e^{-q|x_1-x_2|}\phi(x_2) dx_1dx_2$$

```
mesh.nn = 101;                   % number of nodes 
mesh.x  = linspace(0,a,mesh.nn); % node coordinates, m

[xx,yy] = meshgrid(mesh.x,mesh.x);

MM= exp(-qnorm*abs(yy-xx));
mat= (phi_1.' * phi_2).* MM;

V = trapz(mesh.x,trapz(mesh.x,mat,1),2);
```

Comment: You are writing in a certain computer language, I guess.  So maybe ask in a computer-language forum?

Comment: @GEdgar i have tagged matlab, or if somebody can give a simple answer implemented in any language, I think the key problem is to deal with the integral numerically.

Comment: What is the function $\phi$? And what dow your double integral equation have to do with the Matlab-like code below it? Is that your attempt to perform quadrature integration over an area?

Comment: @horchler phi is a numerical vector not given here(defined on mesh.x).. I have edited the post, anyway, I want to figure out how to implement this integral in an efficient way.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you're not using [`integral2`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral2.html) in Matlab to perform quadrature integration? If you're using an older version of Matlab, try [`quad2d`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad2d.html) or [`dblquad`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dblquad.html). If the problem is that your function $\phi$ is numerical data rather than an analytical function, then you can still use interpolation. For example, if $\phi($ `PHI_XCOORDS` $) = $ `PHI_DATA` then, using [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html):

```
phi = @(x)interp1(PHI_XCOORDS,PHI_DATA,x);
f = @(x1,x2)phi(x1).*exp(-Q.*abs(x1-x2)).*phi(x2);
V = integral2(f,0,A,0,A)
```

Since your code/equations are incomplete I can't really check if this will work or help you further though.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i test it compared to trapz implementation, however, this integral2 with interp1 is much slower..

Comment: You didn't mention anything about speed/performance in your question. It's slower, because it's performing interpolation and more accurate quadrature integration. Your `trapz` method is limited by the density of the mesh you choose and the the simple trapezoidal integration technique, which may or may not be sufficient for the function in question. To try to speed up the `integral2` scheme, try using fewer discrete values for your $\phi$ function and let `interp1` do the interpolation. And/or look at the help for `integral2` and adjust the tolerances.